# How can I detect if a jquery ajax request has been going on for more than 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to tell if a jquery ajax request has been going on for more than a certain length of time? I would like to prompt users of my site if the request has been going on for 10 seconds to reload and retry, but I cant find anything in the documentation to meet my request.

Comment: @Murali setting a short timeout will make the whole request to fail. The question is just about measuring the time a specific request is running, not to cancel it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: Do you want to make this for just one ajax request or for any ajax request? As a "common courtesy" in your web site.

Comment: all ajax @AdrianSalazar

Answer (score 5):

Try setting timeout property and get the error handler parameter. The possible values are

`"timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror"`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function(response) { alert(response); },
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
        } else {
            alert(t);
        }
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

So for all ajax requests in your site... you should do something like this...

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){

          /* Generate a timer for the request */
          jqXHR.timer = setTimeout(function(){

               /* Ask the user to confirm */
               if(confirm(settings.url + ' is taking too long. Cancel request?')){
                   jqXHR.abort();
               }
          }, 10000);
     }
});
```

Comment: Just make sure it runs at the begging of your page loading. Like this $(function(){  /* paste code here */ })

Answer (score 1):

Set a timeout and then cancel it once it ajax call completes.

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Too long!');
}, 10000);

$.getJSON(url, function() {
   clearTimeout(timer);
});
```